# How do I reduce the apparent memory usage of Monero?

Tags: monerod

We all know that LMDB uses a memory-mapped database, so the actual usage of memory by the monero network service process (aka monerod, monero daemon) is very minimal (once network synchronization has completed).

More information on caching and memory mapping can be found [here](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/).

Despite these facts, it is sometimes advantageous to reduce the apparent usage of memory by the monerod process. How can one reduce the apparent memory usage?

Comment: So apparently the answer that someone figured out was wrong.... so this will just sit unanswered for now.

Comment: Yep, got here from Google after seeing this in top: `48.419GB VIRT, 2.579GB RES monerod`

Comment: Why is it advantageous to reduce the apparent (as you put it) memory usage?

Comment: I know one thing I've run into is that virtual machine providers may not like seeing 100% memory usage. But others have provided other reasons at some point or another.

Comment: But that's not how you calculate memory usage on Linux. See: http://www.tothenew.com/blog/understanding-memory-utilization-in-linux/

Also, VPS providers preset amount of memory a VM has access to. If you want to use 100% of it that's fine - that's what you are paying for.

Answer (score 1):

As per comments, Monero memory usage is not an issue here, it's about understanding Linux memory. The usage is not "high" and there is no reason to change anything for those that simply do not understand Linux memory.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: "Monero memory usage is not an issue here" is absolutely an answer. The user is asking how to reduce "apparent memory usage", which is missing the point of how Linux reports memory usage.

Comment: It is an answer to another question that the one that was asked :)

Comment: It is an answer to the question as titled and question at end of post.

Comment: Before the question title was edited that is.

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense, I hadn't seen the original title. Still, the body makes it pretty explicit it's not asking about this :) But whatever I guess.