# VIRT 100G usage of monerod; Is this expected?

Tags: monerod

[image: monerod hogging up the memory]

monerod is (seems) literally hogging up the memory.

Is this expected?

If it's not, what can I do to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority of the virtual memory usage is memory mapped I/O backed by the blockchain database on disk. A minority corresponds the process memory.

The monero database file is something like 70 GB, very roughly, and some extra space is reserved for expansion, so 103 GB seems totally plausible.

As a point of comparison, typical x86_64 has 256 TB of virtual address space, so 104 GB is 0.04% of it.

Comment: OP is asking about RAM not disk space. See image posted.

Comment: The question is about virtual memory...

Comment: The screenshot is RAM (virtual, shared, resident).

Comment: Yes. What's your point ? You're constantly trying to reinterpret things on a technicality. This is not helpful.

Comment: The point is the user is confused by Linux memory and is assuming monerod is hogging memory "monerod is (seems) literally hogging up the memory" - which is not how this works. Your response in no way referenced this and just spoke to blockchain size. Where I see either an inaccurate or misleading answer, I feel duty bound to clarify.

Comment: I think you just know enough to be dangerous. I added a line about why the file size is the reason for this.

Comment: I suggest removing the final line too because virtual address space is a different subject matter to memory usage display in `top`. And the ultimate point to answering this question is to point out high VIRT is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is not hogging all your RAM. Please see duplicate question, answer and comments: [How do I reduce the apparent memory usage of Monero?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4117/how-do-i-reduce-the-apparent-memory-usage-of-monero)

And an explanation of Linux memory as reported by `top`: https://serverfault.com/a/48610

Comment: Also a nice simple explanation of the VIRT, RES and SHR parameters you are looking at in `top`. https://lilyfeng.wordpress.com/2013/07/17/the-difference-among-virt-res-and-shr-in-top-output/